# Azure web roles and vm durability

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles, azure-role-environment

Assume we have extended `RoleEntryPoint` class and overridden `Run()` method. As the documentation states,

> If the Run method returns, the role is automatically recycled by raising the Stopping event and calling the OnStop method so that your shutdown sequences may be executed before the role is taken offline.

I have some questions regarding this

1. What happens to the vm instance if overrode Run() method returns? (Is the vm reclaimed by Azure or shutdown)
2. Is a webrole allocated to a dedicated vm instance or a shared vm instance?
3. Are vms used for web or worker roles are created in an adhoc manner or recycled instances which were created and used earlier? (In this case can we expect old registry key entries are available?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What happens to the vm instance if overrode Run() method returns? (Is
>   the vm reclaimed by Azure or shutdown)

Your vm instance will reboot in this scenario.

> Is a webrole allocated to a dedicated vm instance or a shared vm
>   instance?

You get a dedicated vm instance based on the size your selected.

> Are vms used for web or worker roles are created in an adhoc manner or
>   recycled instances which were created and used earlier? (In this case
>   can we expect old registry key entries are available?)

When you create a new deployment, you will get brand new virtual machines i.e. created from scratch. Thus you can't expect old registry key entries to be available.

Comment: From Azure point of view, is there possibility of using existing vm to be reused for a webrole?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by reusability?

Comment: If I ask this way, it would be clear. Does Azure use some kind of virtual machine farm or pool for these webroles? So that it can quickly roll out these applications. For instance, if something catastrophic thing caused to a vm in a way that is not recoverable, Azure can quickly pick another from the vm pool. SInce Webroles are PAAS i felt it like this. Azure has to  take time to acquire hardware, install os and do a lot time consuming stuff if vms are created in adhoc manner from a fresh copy each time.

Comment: Azure is a not a shed. It is a proper cloud. A VM instance is spun up in about one minute, from nothing (well from an OS image, not really nothing). Compute allocation, network piping, billing setup and what not, all that happens within that time frame.